# WooCommerce wp_insert_post action firing on every save

Tags: actions, wp-insert-post, post-meta, woocommerce-offtopic

```
function initial_product_data ( $post_id ) {
// lets get out of here if this is not a new product
if ( 'product' != $_POST['post_type'] )
    return;

// make sure the post isn't automagically featured
// WTF WooCommerce??!!
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_featured', 'no' );

// automatically set the swatch
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_swatch_type', 'pickers' );    
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_swatch_type_options', unserialize('a:1:{s:7:"pa_size";a:4:{s:4:"type";s:12:"term_options";s:6:"layout";s:7:"default";s:4:"size";s:19:"swatches_image_size";s:10:"attributes";a:3:{s:7:"x-large";a:3:{s:4:"type";s:5:"color";s:5:"color";s:7:"#FFFFFF";s:5:"image";s:1:"0";}s:23:"x-large-toplarge-bottom";a:3:{s:4:"type";s:5:"color";s:5:"color";s:7:"#FFFFFF";s:5:"image";s:1:"0";}s:23:"x-small-topsmall-bottom";a:3:{s:4:"type";s:5:"color";s:5:"color";s:7:"#FFFFFF";s:5:"image";s:1:"0";}}}}') );
}

add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'initial_product_data' );
```

The code works fine and *almost* does what its supposed to do.  However, it seems like it fires *every time* a product is saved and the user can't alter the values set on the initial product creation.

Any suggestions? Or is this a WordPress bug?

Comment: `wp_insert_post()` inserts updates too. This code does exactly what it should.

Comment: The code **does not** do exactly what it should do.  According to the WP Codex, when using wp_insert_post as an ACTION, it should only fire when a post is CREATED and not on every save/edit.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_insert_post

Comment: The codex is wrong. See the source code of `wp_insert_post()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to add in a simple flag that checks whether this is the initial time we've set our defaults, something such as below:

```
function initial_product_data ( $post_id ) {
// lets get out of here if this is not a new product
if ( 'product' != $_POST['post_type'] )
    return;

//Grab our initial meta value, if set will return true else wordpress will return and empty string(falsey)
$initial = get_post_meta($post_id, 'initial', true);

if(!$initial){
    // make sure the post isn't automagically featured
    // WTF WooCommerce??!!
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_featured', 'no' );

    // automatically set the swatch
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_swatch_type', 'pickers' );    
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_swatch_type_options', unserialize('a:1:{s:7:"pa_size";a:4:{s:4:"type";s:12:"term_options";s:6:"layout";s:7:"default";s:4:"size";s:19:"swatches_image_size";s:10:"attributes";a:3:{s:7:"x-large";a:3:{s:4:"type";s:5:"color";s:5:"color";s:7:"#FFFFFF";s:5:"image";s:1:"0";}s:23:"x-large-toplarge-bottom";a:3:{s:4:"type";s:5:"color";s:5:"color";s:7:"#FFFFFF";s:5:"image";s:1:"0";}s:23:"x-small-topsmall-bottom";a:3:{s:4:"type";s:5:"color";s:5:"color";s:7:"#FFFFFF";s:5:"image";s:1:"0";}}}}') );

    //Set our initial check value to true, to prevent the above code running again
    update_post_meta($post_id, 'initial', true);
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'initial_product_data' );
```

That should do the trick and only set the default upon the initial creation of the product.

Comment: This is an interesting solution.  It works but I hate that its a work around.  According to the codex this seems like its a bug.

Comment: I know.  But at this time and place it is the correct thing to do, plus the code is sound.